# sql server full text search, replace, near and forms of

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Im getting trouble with a full text search query. First, my first try is not working because theres a syntax error close to replace (and I dont understand why) (if I do the replace outside the contains it works):

```
declare @what varchar(100) = 'word1 word2'

select *
from tablea
where
    contains(column1, replace(@what, ' ', ' near '))
```

My second problem is about the NEAR and FORMS OF syntax. I tried:

```
'formsof(inflectional, "word1") near formsof(inflectional, "word2")'
```

But its not working. Theres a syntax error too, not in the replace thing, but in the query. Is it possible to use a replace over the @what variable (outside or inside the contains) to get the correct syntax?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't apply the REPLACE function before running the query?

Comment: Nop, Im doing that. Just wondering why.